# 2D Index Assignment Difference between Pandas and Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to assign values to certain columns at a particular subset of rows in an array using numpy, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.zeros((10, 5))
rows = [0, 2, 4, 6, 9]
cols = [1, 2, 3]
proportions = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

test[rows, cols] = proportions
```

However, this returns an error:

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (3,)
```

While, when I try to do the same thing in Pandas, it does work:

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame(test)
test_df.iloc[rows, cols] = proportions

print(test_df)

     0    1    2    3    4
0  0.0  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.0
7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9  0.0  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.0
```

How can I circumvent this issue and make it work in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy indexing doesn't work quite the same way as pandas `.iloc` indexing when you want to use the indices of an array (or multiple arrays) as the index. But you can use `np.ix_`

```
test[np.ix_(rows, cols)] = proportions
```

Comment: Amazing, couldn't find anything on this anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: This is documented in numpy indexing - under the advanced indexing header: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing